# Sort bibliography entries in alphabetical order by the entries' "short" value

Tags: bibliographies, context, context-mkiv, sorting

How can the bibliography list entries be sorted in alphabetical order using the `s` ("short") field of the publication entries in the example below? I don't want to use a BibTeX file, but the `start/stoppublication` commands.

```
\setuppublications[
    alternative=apa-de,
    criterium=text,
    sorttype=cite,  % "cite" oder "bbl" are supported, something like "short" needed
    refcommand=short,  
    numbering=short,  
    autohang=yes,
    setupinteraction=start,
]

\setuppublicationlist[
    samplesize={AAAAAAA},
    author=\invertedauthor,
    artauthor=\invertedauthor,
]

%=== entries ===

\startpublication[
  k=bh2008,
  t=book,
  a={Bringhurst},
  y=2008,
  n=1,
  s={Elements},
]
  \author[]{Robert}[]{}{Bringhurst}
  \pubyear{2008}
  \title{The Elements of Typographic Style}
  \edition{3.2}
  \city{Point Roberts WA, Vancouver}
\stoppublication


\startpublication[
  k=taco1999, 
  t=article,
  a=Hoekwater,
  y=1999,
  s=TH99,
  n=1
]
\artauthor[]{Taco}[T.]{}{Hoekwater}
\arttitle{\CONTEXT\ Publication Module, The user documententation} \journal{MAPS}
\pubyear{To appear}
\note{This article}
\pages{66--76}
\stoppublication


\startpublication [
  k=fielding2000,
  t=phdthesis,
  a={Fielding},
  y=2000,
  n=1,
  s={FIE2000},
]
  \author[]{Roy Thomas}[R. T.]{}{Fielding}
  \title{Architectural Styles and
the Design of Network-based Software Architectures}
  \pubname{University of California, Irvine}
  \isbn{0-599-87118-0}
\stoppublication

%=== /entries ===

\starttext

Foo \cite[fielding2000]. Bar \cite[taco1999]. Baz \cite[bh2008]

\completepublications

\stoptext
```

This results in:

[image: result page 2]

But the wanted order would be:

- Elements
- FIE2000
- TH99

One solution that would work, is to write publication entries in the correct alphabetical order and set `sorttype=bbl`. But this would be too complicated.

Is there an easy way to achive this?

Comment: I don't use bibliographies a lot, but from what I understand the code, sorting based on the `s` key is not implemented. The relevant code is `hacks.flush` function in `bibl-tra.lua` file. You need to add another branch that sorts the list differently when `sorttype=short`. It may be worthwhile to send a feature request to the mailing list

Comment: @Aditya The code in this file doesn't look too difficult. I tried to do it myself, but I'm not familiar with ConTeXt development and was not able to make changes in the file to be recognized at all. Probably because of caching reasons. (Using standalone ConTeXt with `first-setup.sh`) I also tried to "inject" the behaviour from outside, but the entries are stored in the local variable `list`, that seems not to be accessible from other locations. But at least the Tcl+filter way works. :) / I'll also send a feature request to the mailing list.

Comment: To remake the english-interface format files, run `context --make cont-en`. Any changes you made in the ConTeXt sources will then be recognized.

Comment: @Esteis Thanks, good to know. I sent a request to ConTeXt mailing list → Hans Hagen added a `short` option, that should be available in the newest beta.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is a hackish solution: Because I don't know much about ConTeXt/LuaTeX I use an external Tcl script with the `filter` module to sort the `start-/stoppublication` entries.

**bblsorter**:

```tcl
#!/bin/sh 
# the next line restarts using tclsh \
exec tclsh8.6 "$0" "$@"

if {$::argc != 2} {
    puts stderr "Usage: $::argv0 {input file} {output file}"
    exit 1
}

proc getShortname {entry} {
    # maybe improve this quite optimistic regex
    if {[regexp {\\startpublication\s*\[[^\]]*s=\{?(\w+)} $entry _ val]} {
        return $val
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}

proc compareEntry {arg1 arg2} {
    return [string compare [getShortname $arg1] [getShortname $arg2]]
}

set inputFile [lindex $::argv 0]
set outputFile [lindex $::argv 1]

# read input file
set f [open $inputFile]
set fileContent [read $f]
close $f

# split publication entries to list
set bblList [regexp -inline -all -- {\\startpublication.*?\\stoppublication} $fileContent]

# sort publication list
set sortedBblList [lsort -command compareEntry $bblList]

# write sorted publication list
set f [open $outputFile w]
puts $f [join $sortedBblList "\n\n"]
close $f
```

To keep everything simple, the Tcl script expects a well-formed input file. No error detection is done.

**main.tex**:

```
\usemodule[filter] 

\defineexternalfilter
    [bblsorter]
    [filtercommand={./bblsorter \externalfilterinputfile\space \externalfilteroutputfile}]


\setuppublications[
    alternative=apa-de,
    criterium=text,
    sorttype=bbl,
    refcommand=short,  
    numbering=short,  
    autohang=yes,
    setupinteraction=start,
]

\setuppublicationlist[
    samplesize={AAAAAAA},
    author=\invertedauthor,
    artauthor=\invertedauthor,
]

%=== entries ===

\startbblsorter

    \startpublication[
      k=bh2008,
      t=book,
      a={Bringhurst},
      y=2008,
      n=1,
      s={Elements},
    ]
      \author[]{Robert}[]{}{Bringhurst}
      \pubyear{2008}
      \title{The Elements of Typographic Style}
      \edition{3.2}
      \city{Point Roberts WA, Vancouver}
    \stoppublication


    \startpublication[
      k=taco1999, 
      t=article,
      a=Hoekwater,
      y=1999,
      s=TH99,
      n=1
    ]
    \artauthor[]{Taco}[T.]{}{Hoekwater}
    \arttitle{\CONTEXT\ Publication Module, The user documententation} \journal{MAPS}
    \pubyear{To appear}
    \note{This article}
    \pages{66--76}
    \stoppublication


    \startpublication [
      k=fielding2000,
      t=phdthesis,
      a={Fielding},
      y=2000,
      n=1,
      s={FIE2000},
    ]
      \author[]{Roy Thomas}[R. T.]{}{Fielding}
      \title{Architectural Styles and
    the Design of Network-based Software Architectures}
      \pubname{University of California, Irvine}
      \isbn{0-599-87118-0}
    \stoppublication

\stopbblsorter

%=== /entries ===

\starttext

Foo \cite[fielding2000]. Bar \cite[taco1999]. Baz \cite[bh2008]

\completepublications

\stoptext
```

This works and is not really complex because of the really great `filter` module. But a pure ConTeXt solution might probably be better and more robust.

Comment: Very creative use of the filter module!